# How to remove overlap menu control in Bottom app bar? Please explain it in Kotlin

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, kotlin-coroutines

I want to design a Bottom app bar,
First i implemented a dependency named as
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
After that with the help of co-ordinate layout I started the project
The xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My style.xml is

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

And my menu resource file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
        android:title="Profile">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Book"
        android:title="Courses"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_book_24"
        >

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        >

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
        android:title="Settings"
        >

    </item>
</menu>
```

And default the overlap menu control also viewed on the activityscreen!I need to remove that[This is the activity_image,I need to remove the bottom right three dots on the bottomAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wgkc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand currectly then, In menu.xml file edit below code:

```
 app:showAsAction="always"
```

which display string or icon if define in menu item.
For Example only text without icon:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

For Example with icon:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: that's okay!but i cant remove the overlap menu control in the bottom app bar? I cant able to remove that three dots

Comment: Tq for ur reply!NICE WORK BUD

Answer (score 1):

I had got this same problem. Your `app:menu="@menu/menu"` add default this three dots (I dont know why).

Try add bottom navigation bar between BottomAppBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"/>

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And if you have a shadow, you must write this in MainActivity/onCreate:

```
    val navigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)

    navigationView.background = null
```